# Dimensional analysis in QFT

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, dimensional-analysis, dirac-equation

I have the Lagrangian density:

$$\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - M)\psi$$

How do I know what dimensions $\bar{\psi}$ and $\psi$ have?

Comment: Reassure the reader you know what dimensions the lagrangian density and the action have....

Comment: dimension of lagrangian is [L] = 4

Comment: If you know $[L]$, what problem were you having determining $[\psi]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the Lagrangian density:

> $$\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - M)\psi$$

> How do I know what dimensions $\bar{\psi}$ and $\psi$ have?

Per your comment, you seem to know that the dimension of $\mathcal{L}$ is $E^4$. (Which is true in 3+1 spacetime dimensions.)

The gamma matrices are dimensionless ($E^0$) and partial derivatives like $\partial_\mu$ have dimension $\frac{1}{L}=E^1$.

Therefore, if the dimension of $\psi$ is written $E^x$ (which is the same as the dimension of $\bar \psi$) you must solve the following equation for $x$:
$$
E^{x}E^0 E^1 E^x = E^4\;.
$$